# Morpho-phonological insertion in syntactic tree

Tags: forest, trees, linguistics

I need to draw a tree that partially reproduces one from a paper I'm citing in my dissertation. With the following code I obtain the tree below. However, what I need is to draw the connection between D and C as a double (vertical) arrow, since it's representing a morph-phonological insertion (the author drew it like this, with a double arrow, and this part needs to be reproduced).
Any tips on how to achieve the result?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
 [bP [C,baseline,  [D] ] [...]
  ]  \end{forest}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `edge` to define the connection:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [bP
            [C,baseline,
                [D, edge={Implies-, double}]
            ]
            [...]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]